# Jquery Function Return value but but not pass to controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I click on edit link then getbyID function call and return two parameters when I debug js code function getbyID return getbyID(16,1) but this value does not pass to controller function. Show message "Parameter dictionary contain null entry mReq_ID_Det and mSrno". anyone tell where I am wrong and what is the problem in this code.

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetbyID(Int64 mReq_ID_Det,int mSrno )
        {
            Requisition mReq = new Requisition();
            mReq = mRequisition_Select(mReq_ID_Det,mSrno);
            return Json(mReq, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        #endregion


        #region Select Requisition for Edit 
        public Requisition mRequisition_Select(Int64 mReq_ID_Det, int mSrNo)
        {

            try
            {
                Requisition mReq = new Requisition();


                con = new SqlConnection(constring);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Req_ID_Det,SrNo,ItemCode,Qty,Remarks from RequisitionDetail where Req_ID_Det='"+ mReq_ID_Det + "' and SrNo='"+mSrNo+"'", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();

                DataTable mDT = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(mDT);
                mReq.Req_ID_Det = mDT.Rows[0]["Req_ID_Det"].ToString();
                mReq.Srno = int.Parse(mDT.Rows[0]["SrNo"].ToString());
                mReq.ItemCode = mDT.Rows[0]["ItemCode"].ToString();
                mReq.Qty = float.Parse(mDT.Rows[0]["Qty"].ToString());
                mReq.Remarks = mDT.Rows[0]["Remarks"].ToString();

                con.Close();
                return mReq;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

**Javascript:**

```
function loadData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("RequisitionList")',
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                var html = '';

                $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td style="display:none">' + item.Req_ID_Det + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Srno + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.ItemDesc + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Qty + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + item.Remarks + '</td>';
                    html += '<td style=""> <a href="" onclick="return getbyID(' + item.Req_ID_Det + ',' + item.Srno.toString() + ')">Edit</a></td>';

                    html += '</tr>';
                });
                $('.flist').html(html);
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
    }

 function getbyID(mReq_ID_Det, mSrno) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetbyID/" + mReq_ID_Det + "$" + mSrno,
            typr: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#Req_ID_Det').val(result.Req_ID_Det);
                $('#Srno').val(result.Srno);
                $('#ItemCode').val(result.ItemCode);
                $('#Qty').val(result.Qty);
                $('#Remarks').val(result.Remarks);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                $('#saveRequisition').show();

            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `url: "/Home/GetbyID/" + mReq_ID_Det + "$" + mSrno,` should be `url: "/Home/GetbyID?mReq_ID_Det=" + mReq_ID_Det + "&mSrno=" + mSrno,`  If you have not specified route specfically to treat the last parts of URL as parameters

Comment: Problem Resolve thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on `typr` which should be `type`. Also, you are simply adding the value of the parameters on the url and not on a query string.

You could try:

```
function getbyID(mReq_ID_Det, mSrno) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetbyID/".
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            mReq_ID_Det: mReq_ID_Det,
            mSrno: mSrno
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#Req_ID_Det').val(result.Req_ID_Det);
            $('#Srno').val(result.Srno);
            $('#ItemCode').val(result.ItemCode);
            $('#Qty').val(result.Qty);
            $('#Remarks').val(result.Remarks);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#saveRequisition').show();

        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```